# MongoDB match on document and subdocuments, what to use as indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have a lot of documents looking like this:

```
[{
        "title": "Luxe [daagse] [verzorging] @ Egypte! Incl. vluchten, transfers & 4* ho",
        "price": 433,
        "automatic": false,
        "destination": "5d26fc92f72acc7a0b19f2c4",
        "date": "2020-01-19T00:00:00.000+00:00",
        "days": 8,
        "arrival_airport": "5d1f5b407ec7385fa2963623",
        "departure_airport": "5d1f5adb7ec7385fa2963307",
        "board_type": "5d08e1dfff6c4f13f6db1e6c"
    },
    {
        "title": "Luxe [daagse] [verzorging] @ Egypte! Incl. vluchten, transfers & 4* ho",
        "automatic": true,
        "destination": "5d26fc92f72acc7a0b19f2c4",
        "prices": [{
                "price": 433,
                "date_from": "2020-01-19T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "date_to": "2020-01-28T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "day_count": 8,
                "arrival_airport": "5d1f5b407ec7385fa2963623",
                "departure_airport": "5d1f5adb7ec7385fa2963307",
                "board_type": "5d08e1dfff6c4f13f6db1e6c"
            },
            {
                "price": 899,
                "date_from": "2020-04-19T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "date_to": "2020-04-28T00:00:00.000+00:00",
                "day_count": 19,
                "arrival_airport": "5d1f5b407ec7385fa2963623",
                "departure_airport": "5d1f5adb7ec7385fa2963307",
                "board_type": "5d08e1dfff6c4f13f6db1e6c"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, automatic deals have multiple prices (can be a lot, between 1000 and 4000) and does not have the original fields available.

Now I need to search in the original document as well in the subdocuments to look for a match.

This is the aggregation I use to search through the documents:

```
[{
    "$match": {
        "destination": {
            "$in": ["5d26fc9af72acc7a0b19f313"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "$or": [{
            "prices": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "price": {
                        "$lte": 1500,
                        "$gte": 400
                    },
                    "date_to": {
                        "$lte": "2020-04-30T22:00:00.000Z"
                    },
                    "date_from": {
                        "$gte": "2020-03-31T22:00:00.000Z"
                    },
                    "board_type": {
                        "$in": ["5d08e1bfff6c4f13f6db1e68"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            "price": {
                "$lte": 1500,
                "$gte": 400
            },
            "date": {
                "$lte": "2020-04-30T22:00:00.000Z",
                "$gte": "2020-03-31T22:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "board_type": {
                "$in": ["5d08e1bfff6c4f13f6db1e68"]
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    "$limit": 20
}]
```

I would like to speed things up, because it can be quite slow. I was wondering, what is the best index strategy for this aggregate, what fields do I use? Is this the best way of doing it or is there a better way?

Comment: It does work, maybe I copied something wrong. You can use $in like this right? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: Thats true, but in [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) we have to use queries. My aggregation works, so please don't worry about that. Can we focus on the question?

Comment: In general indexes are most sufficient when you have distinct values. In this case I would try to create index for `createIndex( {"prices.board_type": 1} )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compound index including the match filter fields is required to make the aggregation run fast. In aggregation queries, having the `$match` stage early in the pipeline (preferably, first stage) utilizes indexes, if any are defined on the filter fields. In the posted query it is so, and defining the indexes is all needed for a fast query. But, index on what fields?

The index is going to be ***compound index***; i.e., index on multiple fields of the query criteria. The index prefix starts with the `destination` field. The remaining index fields are to be determined. What are the remaining fields?

Most of these fields are in the `prices` array's sub-document fields - `price`, `date_from`, `date_to` and `board_type`. There is also the `date` field from the main document. Which of these fields need to be used in the compound index?

Defining indexes on array elements (or fields of sub-documents in an array) creates lots of index keys. This means lots of storage and for using the index the memory (or RAM). This is an important consideration. Indexes on array elements are called as ***multikey indexes***. For an index to be properly utilized, the collection's documents and the index being used by the query (together called as ***working set***) must fit into the RAM.

Another aspect you need to consider is the ***query selectivity***. How many documents gets selected using a filter which uses an index field, is a factor. It is imperative that the filter field with must select a small set of the input documents to be effective. See [Create Queries that Ensure Selectivity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-queries-that-ensure-selectivity/).

It is difficult to determine what other fields need to be considered (sure some of the fields of the `prices`) based on the above two factors. So, the index is going to be something like this:

```
{ destination: 1, fld1: 1, fld2: 1, ... }
```

The `fld1`, `fld2`, ..., are going to be the `prices` array sub-document fields and / or the `date` field. I think only one set of date fields can be used with the index. An example index can be one of these:

```
{ destination: 1, date: 1,  "prices.price": 1, "prices.board_type": 1}
{ destination: 1, "prices.price": 1, "prices.date_from": 1, "prices.date_to": 1, "prices.board_type": 1}
```

Note the index keys *order* and the *necessity* of the `price`, `date_from`, `date_to` and `board_type` is to be determined based upon the two main factors - requirement of the working set and the query selectivity - this is important.

**NOTES**: On a small sample data set with similar structure showed usage of the compound index with the primary `destination` field and two fields from the `prices` (one with equality condition and one with range condition). The ***query plan*** using the `explain` showed an IXSCAN (index scan) on the compound index, and using an index will sure improve the query performance.

Answer (score 3):

From Mongo's [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) docs:

> When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by indexes, MongoDB performs index scans. That is, for MongoDB to use indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or expression must be supported by indexes. Otherwise, MongoDB will perform a collection scan.

So with that in mind in order to avoid a collection scan in this pipeline you have to create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) containing both `price` and `prices` fields.

Remember that order matters in compound indexes so the order of the field should vary depending on your possible usage of it.

It seems to me that the index you want to create looks something like:

```
{destination: 1, date: 1, board_type: 1, price: 1, prices: 1}
```

Comment: When you use `prices: 1`, is that a wildcard or something? What about for example the `date` and the `board_type` fields, do I also need to set indexes on them? 

I find it hard to think what indexes to set, because a visitor can select what kind of filters he want to use. 

Sometimes the visitor is filtering on `price` and `board_type` and the other moment the visitor is filtering on `date / date_from / date_to` and `price`.

Comment: `prices: 1` just means its an ascending index, you do need to add `date` and `board_type` yes i forgot them. You should think about all possible cases and create an index to fit each case if you care about performance in all of those queries. remember that you might be able to use the same index for two different queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can create an index on prices (if there are thousands) [Index Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Index-Key-Limit)

Comment: It depends, some documents have 300 price subdocuments, some have 3000. It looks like I can create an index on prices when I try.

Comment: @tomslabbaert don't I need to specify the fields in the subdocument I want to index on? It will be a lot of different indexes I have to manually specify, is there a quicker or better alternative to do that?

Comment: You don't have to specify subdocument fields, it's better to do so if theres "redundant" fields as in you will never query them.

Comment: When I do use `prices: 1` that index becomes +/- 350MB.